# Change text and add a href to span element Issue

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `span` with an id of `randomText` and the HTML of`changingText`.

What I would like is the jQuery or plain JavaScript code to change the content when the window is resized.

When the window is less than `480px` (this to be both, when the user resizes the browser to less than 480px or when the user uses a mobile device that is less than 480px and do not have to resize the browser) to change the HTML of the `span` to say `I have changed` and set an href to the new HTML content that when the user press it to go to www.google.com. If the user is more than 480px to go to the original text without the href.

It is something simple but I would appreciate it if someone could help.

```
<span id="randomText">changingText</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
$(function(){
$(window).on("resize", function(){
    if($(window).width()<480){
        $("#randomText").html("<a id='changingTextWrapper' href='www.google.com'>I changed!</a>");
    }else{
        $("#randomText").html('changingText');
    }
});
if($(window).width()<480){
        $("#randomText").html("<a id='changingTextWrapper' href='www.google.com'>I changed!</a>");
    }
```

});

Comment: Thank u @ NotanNimba for ur answer but ur code is not working.

Comment: Yeah i did put 479 instead of 480 it should work now

Comment: What if the window width is 480? You probably should use `if($(window).width() >= 480){...}` in `isWidthHigherThan480` function

Comment: I have tested the code in codepen. The text change when i resize it below 480px but it does not add the link. Also when i resize the browser above 480px the text wont change.

Comment: As Darren Swenney Said you should add a = symbol After one of the if statements this will make the code even better :)